# Redefine variable under same name

Tags: python

I've been trying to create a program which does definite integrals by numerical methods. The problem is that the user has to input his function and then I have to redefine the variable three times, as the formula I have decuced for the integral can be separated in three section which are later summed.

The code is as follows:

```
import math

a = float(input("Lower limit:"))
b = float(input("Upper Limit:"))
ws = 0.01

x = ws * (a + (ws / 2))

f = eval(input("Function (variabl must be x): "))

x = 5 

f1 = f

print(f)
print(f1)
```

As you can see I'm defining a variable `x` and giving it a value so that than I can print the value of the function that I inputted. Then the program should return the value of the function for that first value of `x`.

Later I try to change the value of `x` and print the function `f` (which I renamed as `f1`) for the new value of `x`. However, this does not work and it just prints the value for the first value of `x`.

How can I do this correctly?

Comment: You can try saving just the string input then doing the `eval` later?

Comment: if you want to do something more complex then see [SymPy](https://www.sympy.org/en/index.html) for symbolic mathematics

Answer (score 0):

You have to keep it as text and run `eval` after setting new `x`

```
import math

a = float(input("Lower limit: "))
b = float(input("Upper Limit: "))
ws = 0.01

text = input("Function (variabl must be x): ")

x = (ws * (a + (ws / 2)))
f = eval(text)
print(f)

x = 5 
f = eval(text)
print(f)

for x in range(0, 10):
    f = eval(text)
    print('x:', x, 'f(x):', f)
```